# Which bootstrap css and javascript files should be linked to our html page?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have downloaded the latest [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) version 4 in my computer and  it contains two folder one `css` and other `js`. The css folder contains about 12 css files whereas the js folder contains about 5 javascript files. Do we need to link all these 17 files to our html page? Is there a simple way to link css and js  by folder?

Comment: Just link the min.css and min.js files

Comment: The [Bootstrap 4.6 documents page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/getting-started/introduction/) has the links for the Bootstrap 4.6 CSS and JavaScript files and jQuery files that you can copy and paste into your page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, just use these two files:

1. `bootstrap.min.css`
2. `bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

You can serve them locally if you want, but it's simplest to just use a CDN. For example, these are the v5.1.3 jsDelivr links:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Find the most up-to-date CDN links at [getbootstrap.com](https://getbootstrap.com) under the jsDelivr section.

---

The other files are just trimmed versions of the full bootstrap distribution. They are only needed if you *don't* want the full library and you only want some specific feature(s).

For example, if you *only* want to use bootstrap's grid system and no other bootstrap features, you can use `bootstrap-grid.min.css` instead of the full `bootstrap.min.css`.

| CSS files | Layout | Content | Components | Utilities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| bootstrap(.min).css | Included | Included | Included | Included |
| bootstrap-grid(.min).css | [Only grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/) | ✗ | ✗ | [Only flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/) |
| bootstrap-reboot(.min).css | ✗ | [Only reboot styles](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/reboot/) | ✗ | ✗ |
| bootstrap-utilities(.min).css | ✗ | ✗ | ✗ | Included |

| JS files | Popper | jQuery |
| --- | --- | --- |
| bootstrap.bundle(.min).js | Included | ✗ |
| bootstrap(.min).js | ✗ | ✗ |

Answer (score 1):

Following are the files to attach for the version of bootstrap-4.0.0,
[Download Bootstrap from this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)

For CSS,

```
<link href="~/YourPath/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

For JS,

```
<script src="~/YourPath/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside < head >:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

If you are using Bootstrap4 and want to use Javascript, you need to include JQuery before you include the bootstrap javascript tag:
before </ body>

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```